# Retornar a media de palavras em um dicionario a partir de outra função

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu preciso de uma função que recebe o resultado de uma função de contar palavras e com base nesses valores, essa função calcula a média de quantas vezes determinada palavra aparece no texto, armazena essa média em um dicionário e retorna o dicionário com a esse valor.

exemplo:

```
Parâmetro: ‘{‘três’: 2, ‘pratos’:1}
Retorno: {'três': 0.25, 'pratos': 0.125}
```

Eu consegui fazer a função conta palavras, porem estou com dificuldade para calcular a media em que cada palavra aparece.

```
def conta_palavras(x):
    palavras = {}

    for palavra in x.split():
        if palavra in palavras:
            palavras[palavra] += 1
        else:
            palavras[palavra] = 1

    return palavras

def conta_media_palavras(x):
    palavras = conta_palavras
    maximo = 0
    freq = ''
    for palavra in palavras:
        if palavras[palavra] > maximo:
            maximo = palavras[palavra]
            freq = palavra
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está bem formulada e ainda falta dados para compreendermos melhor a situação. Qual texto você está falando antes de mostrar o parâmetro?. Enfim, tente usar a função `count()` para contar as palavras.

Comment: Victor como o WhoisMatt disse, sua pergunta realmente está mal formulada, tente edita-la e colocar um código mais apresentável para que possamos te ajudar. Quanto mais detalhado for a pergunta mais fácil de conseguir ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Na função `conta_media_palavras` você precisa chamar a função `contar_palavras`. Da maneira que você fez apenas definiu um novo nome para a mesma função, não a chamou.

Ao invés de `palavras = conta_palavras` você deve fazer `palavras = conta_palavras(x)`. Os parenteses indicam que será uma chamada de função passando o valor de `x` como parâmetro.

Depois disso você terá que contar a quantidade de palavras que existe na frase inicial. Você pode fazer isso a partir do próprio dicionário retornado por `contar_palavras`:

```
quantidade = sum(item[1] for item in palavras.item())
```

Ou direto da frase em `x`:

```
quantidade = len(x.split())
```

O resultado deve ser o mesmo. Com a quantidade de palavras, basta você iterar sobre o seu dicionário e dividir a frequência da palavra pela quantidade, possivelmente retornando isso em outro dicionário:

```
def conta_media_palavras(x):
    palavras = contar_palavras(x)
    quantidade = len(x.split())
    media = {}

    for palavra, frequencia in palavras.items():
        media[palavra] = frequencia / quantidade

    return media
```

Você pode usar *dict comprehension* para reescrever a função:

```
 def conta_media_palavras(x):
    palavras = contar_palavras(x)
    quantidade = len(x.split())
    media = {palavra: frequencia / quantidade for palavra, frequencia in palavras.items()}

    return media
```

E para melhorar a função `contar_palavras` leia sobre `collections.defaultdict` e `collections.Counter`.